# supervisord logs don't show my output

Tags: python, logging, supervisord

I have a [program:x] running and it prints / sys.stdout.writes a lot of things. None of which comes up in either in the AUTO childlogdir of [supervisord] or in stdout_logfile of [program:x] 
Am I missing something?

How do I capture all that is printed or stdout-ed from [program:x] ?

In my program I am explicitly doing both,

```
print "something"
sys.stdout.write("something")
```

Relevant supervisord.conf file

```
[supervisord]
childlogdir = %(here)s/../logs/supervisord/
logfile = %(here)s/../logs/supervisord/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes = 100MB
logfile_backups = 10
loglevel = info
pidfile = %(here)s/../logs/supervisord/supervisord.pid
umask = 022
nodaemon = false
nocleanup = false

[program:x]
directory = %(here)s/../
command = python file.py
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true  
stdout_logfile = /appropriate-path/to/access.log
```

Comment: Are you certain the program prints to `stdout` and not `stderr`?

Comment: edited the question with more info. When I do a sys.stdout.write, it should be printing to stdout

Comment: And what is your supervisord config for that `[program:..]`? Oh, and try a `sys.stdout.flush()` as well to make sure it's not the buffer.

Comment: I put in the entire conf file. Also, I tried putting a `sys.stdout.flush()` at the end of my file.py but no luck.

Comment: If you check your supervisord log file, do you actually see that your process was started? If the program never ran, it cannot output anything.

Comment: What version of supervisord? I cannot reproduce your problem locally with 3.0a10; it *could* be 3.0b1 broke something, but let's see your version number first.

Comment: @MarkHildreth my program runs fine.

Comment: Yes my version is supervisor==3.0b1 
I will go back to a stabler one, rerun and notify back.

Comment: And no repo with 3.0b1 either.

Comment: I am now at supervisor==3.0a12 but no luck. So, nothing to do with supervisord version I suppose.

Comment: 3.0b1 *is* the most current version. `a` in 3.0a12 stands for `alpha`, which usually comes before `beta`. :-) We've used supervisord 3.0 alpha releases in production for years now.

Comment: ohh I got it the other way round! But anyhow, the problem is somewhere else and not in supervisord 3.0b1 is what I feel. Thanks for all the help. Will try to do some more trials to fix this or will go some other route.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sys.stdout.flush() helped. I was doing it in the wrong place earlier. you can post that as the answer. thanks.

Comment: @zubinmehta: there you go.

Comment: This is happening to me on a PHP command-line app. It logs fine for a while, then suddenly just stops logging, even though the app continues to run as expected. This is HIGHLY inconvenient behavior for this particular app, and my attempts to ob_flush() and flush() have not improved the issue. WTF is going on...

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Python output is buffered. Setting the [environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED) in you `supervisord.conf` will disable buffering and show log messages sooner:

```
[program:x]
environment = PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

or add the [`-u` command-line switch](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u) to `python` command:

```
[program:x]
command = python -u file.py
```

Alternatively you can flush the `sys.stdout` handler explicitly:

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```

On python 3.3 and up, you can add the `flush=True` parameter to have the function do this for you:

```
print(something, flush=True)
```

Answer (score 48):

You can run your program like this:

```
python -u file.py
```

this will produce unbuffered output

Comment: Proper (15char)

Answer (score 1):

If you have python based script that you can't or don't want to change to flush output on a regular base then you can use [unbuffer](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unbuffer) from the Expect package.

For a Django application in a docker container I've lately used it like that (from a shell script run from supervisord):

```
unbuffer python -u manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:11000 2>&1 >> /var/log/django.log
```